# How are tokens mapped with words in embeddings vector space?

Tags: nlp, spacy, tokenize

I have been trying to learn some basics of AI using spacy, and trying to understand the internals of tokenization/embeddings, before moving on to complex topics like transformers. My question is generic, but am asking it in the context of spacy.

Specifically, how does spacy map a token it generates for the word in the input text with its corresponding embedding? What is the common entity that associates the two- how are they "joined"? I have read that tokenization and embeddings can be done separately, by different algorithms. This makes it even more difficult to understand how spacy's tokens can be associated with non-spacy created embeddings!  I wonder if spacy extracts the lemma (word) from its token, and then checks if that word/lemma is in the vector space. Is token stored as some number by spacy, or as some data structure? Is there some "standard" to map token-to-word-in-embeddings mappings??

As an example, if word2vec embeddings are used, how does spacy map the tokens it generates with the data in this vector space?? There is something tying the two databases(?) that I am not able to grasp.

Thanks for any clarifications on some underlying mechanics!

Read/saw a number of articles/posts/videos, but feel that most gloss over such details. A simple end-to-end explanation of the workflow, with just enough details would be very helpful.